# How to rotate multiple sums in a single query from columns into rows

Tags: mysql, sum, pivot

I have searched all the answers database and honestly haven't found what I need. I have a table with contract values and the date related to each of this values. My query is supposed to sum the contract values acumulated for the last 6 months, beginning from the current date and looking back 3 months, always considering a 6 month acumulation period:

```
SELECT
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) AS Today, 
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) AS OneMonthAgo,
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) AS TwoMonthsAgo, 
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) AS ThreeMonthsAgo 
FROM Contracts
```

The query works fine but I get the results in a single row, with the acumulated values each one in a different column:

```
+----+---------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|    | Today   | OneMonthAgo | TwoMonthsAgo | ThreeMonthsAgo | 
+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
|  1 | 3434005 |   3992877   |    4104565   |     3688412    |
+--------------+-------------+--------------+----------------+
```

What I need is to make this query into a graph, and to do that, instead of columns, the acumulated results should appear as rows, or something like this:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
|  LookingTo    |  AcumulatedContractValue (6 months)  | 
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
|    Today      |              3434005                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| OneMonthAgo   |              3992877                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
| TwoMonthsAgo  |              4104565                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
|ThreeMonthsAgo |              3688412                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------+
```

If it was in MS SQL, I believe PIVOT should work but I don't know how to do it in MySQL. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why do you need that but you can just union:

```
SELECT 'Today' as `LookingTo`,
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 0 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) as  Acumulated
FROM Contracts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'OneMonthAgo',
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue)
FROM Contracts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'TwoMonthsAgo',
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue)  
FROM Contracts
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ThreeMonthsAgo',
SUM((ContractDate > DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH), INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AND (ContractDate <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 3 MONTH)) AND (ContractCancelled <>1)) * ContractValue) 
FROM Contracts
```

Comment: let me now what the fields meaning : ContractCancelled and ContractValue. Why do you have this (ContractCancelled <>1) in your query. I will send you a optimized query when i understand your query.

is it right that you only want to sum from ContractValue from a day and the same day 1,2 3 month ago when ContractCancelled is not equal 1 ?

Comment: I want to sum from ContractValue every contract value in a 6 month interval. Let's say, today is september, 28th, then I want the query to give me the sum for every contract from April 28th trough September 28th. And looking back, I want the sum of contract amounts from March 28th trough August 28th and also from Ferbruary 28th through July 28th. This way the user can compare the amount of contracts (in currency) have been signed (and not cancelled, as checked through ContractCancelled field) in the last 6 months and compare it with the situation one and two months ago.